# Which HTTP response code to send on unhandled request

Tags: php, http, httprequest, httpresponse

I have a PHP application that has a router that should have two default handlers for `401 Unauthorized` and `404 Not Found`.

But it could happen that no handlers were set for those two cases. In that case, I need to have a default response that tells `Request Unhandled`, I have set it to the response code `400 Bad Request`, but I feel like its not truly appropriate.

What response code should I use for a unhandled request?

Comment: 4xx is generally a client's problem. 5xx is your problem. So if you cannot handle a request - it is HTTP 5xx. For example - `501 Not Implemented`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

4xx is generally a client's problem. 5xx is your (server-side) problem. So if you cannot handle a request - it is HTTP 5xx.

In this case it looks that `501 Not Implemented` is the best fit.

References:

- http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error